# Unable to install fs-ext using npm: error C3861: 'fcntl': identifier not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm getting the following error while installing fs-ext. I have Win10-64bit machine with Node- v8.1.3, npm - v5.4.0 
Any suggestions on how to install it successfully?

```
PS C:\users\desktop\auth> npm install fs-ext

    > fs-ext@0.6.0 install C:\users\desktop\auth\node_modules\fs-ext
    > node-gyp configure build


    C:\users\desktop\auth\node_modules\fs-ext>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure build )  else (                                                                                                              node "" configure build )
    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
      fs-ext.cc
      win_delay_load_hook.cc
    ..\fs-ext.cc(195): error C3861: 'fcntl': identifier not found [C:\users\desktop\auth\node_modules\fs-ext\bui
    ld\fs-ext.vcxproj]
    ..\fs-ext.cc(374): error C3861: 'fcntl': identifier not found [C:\users\desktop\auth\node_modules\fs-ext\bui
    ld\fs-ext.vcxproj]
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The current NPM version, 0.6.0, was released 6 months ago.  In Github 2 months ago, there were a series of commits that fixed Windows compatibility, but these don't seem to have made it to NPM.  https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext

I'd go to node_modules/fs-ext and sync this with github to see if this fixes the issue, or contact the maintainer and ask that he put out a 0.7.0 or 0.6.1 with these recent fixes.